# Tanimoto distance representing function

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions

Tanimoto distance between A,B is :$$ T(A,B)= 1- 
\frac{A \cdot B}{\|A\|^2+\|B\|^2-A \cdot B}
$$
It is proven that Tanimoto distance is a proper distance [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1019154432472)

I want to find the representing function of Tanimoto distance to make it usable as a distance based loss like in the book [Support Vector Machines](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-77242-4)(page 38) where it define the representing function of a distance based loss as :

Definition 2.32. We say that a supervised loss $L: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ is:

i) distance-based if there exists a representing function $\psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ satisfying $\psi(0)=0$ and
$$
L(y, t)=\psi(y-t), \quad y \in Y, t \in \mathbb{R}
$$

I am having troubles finding this representing function for Tanimoto distance, does anyone knows how to derive it ?

Comment: Based on the appearance of dot products and norms the Tanimoto function is a map $T : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto U \subset \mathbb{R}$ thus does not match the definition of the supervised loss function $L: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mapsto [0,\infty]$.

Comment: @Galen what if we restrict the values of A,B to [0,1] , I think it is used for binary values from the beginning so this makes more sense.  
$T : [0,1]^n \times[0,1]^n \mapsto U \subset \mathbb{R_{+}}$

Comment: @Galen [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1019154432472)  it says that the output of Tanimoto distance will range between [0,1]  ,and I quote:
$$
S_{m n}=\frac{X_{m n}}{X_{m m}+X_{n n}-X_{m n}}
$$
where $X_{i j}=\mathbf{X}_i \cdot \mathbf{X}_j$. The value of $S_{m n}$ ranges from 0 to $1 .$